# Get Custom HiDPI resolution rendering on non-Retina Macs

Tags: resolution

On MacBook Pro with Retina Display, Apple samples image to 2x and then scale it back down. Even for other resolutions found in System Preferences.

However, on other Macs, that doesn't work. They simply provide one default resolution for HiDPI, and then others are all scaled.

Is there any possibilities that this can be configured on a non-Retina Mac?

Answer (score 2):

This forum post answers your question: [InsanelyMac - Custom Retina HiDPI Resolution](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/290097-guide-add-your-custom-retina-hidpi-resolution-for-your-desktop-display/)

It's pretty lengthy and complex, and probably not for someone who isn't happy with messing about with the terminal and plists etc.  In essence the steps involve messing with the `DisplayProductID` and `DisplayVendorID` values to fool the OS into thinking it's a HiDPI display.

It's not fair to simply plagiarise the OPs post, as this is from another user on another site, rather than a generic "use this program' style suggestion, so you'll have to follow the link rather than have it all pasted in here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But answers containing just links to forum post are not optimal in Ask Different. Please consider adding more information to improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can, Download the app Display Monitor https://github.com/Eun/DisableMonitor 
install and then you can change it